# Doing AJAX CC tokenisation action in form submission event and waiting for result

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, opayo

I am trying to integrate the Sage Pay Pi (REST) gateway into a form,
but having some difficulties trying to implement it. One thing I am 
trying to do, is to avoid the use of `preventDefault` on the payment
form, since that then forces my code to take over the actual submission
of the form.

What I would like to happen when the user submits the form, containing
both credit card fields and address fields, is this:

- The Sage Pay library validates the credit card fields. Any errors are
  highlighted and the form is prevented from submitting.
- If the CC fields validate, then an AJAX call (through the gateway code)
  tokenises the card details and inserts the tokenised details into the
  form.
- If the tokenisation fails, then errors are highlighted and the form does
  not get submitted. (A session token refresh m,ay be tried in this process,
  but I'll treat that as out of scope here)
- Given the above has not failed, all further events on the form fire, which
  cover validation on other fields in the form, and the form is submitted as
  normal.

So the concept is that if nothing explicitly fails in the events tied to the
form, then it will submit. Any one of a number of things could fail to allow
the form to submit. I understand returning `false` from the submit event can
achieve this.

So the problem I have is the synchronous nature of the AJAX card tokenisation.
Here is a run-down of the JS structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/js/sagepay.js"></script>

<form id="checkout-form">...CC fields...personal and address fielss...</form>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#checkout-form')
        .addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            // Event handler
            sagepayOwnForm({ merchantSessionKey: "my-session-key"})
                .tokeniseCardDetails({
                    cardDetails: {...selectors to get the CC details...},
                    onTokenised: function(result) {
                        // In here check the tokenisation result.
                        // If successful, then put the result.token in the form.
                        // If not successful, then display error and STOP the
                        // default form submit action.
                        // In either case, DO allow all remaining events to fire
                    }
                })
        });
</script>
```

My problem is that `onTokenised` is asynchronous. The form is submitted immediately,
and does not wait for the AJAX card tokenisation process to finish.
I cannot make the AJAX synchronous, because it is all deep inside the gateway
JavaScript in `sagepayOwnForm`.

- I would like the event handler to wait fot the tokeniser to get a result before it exits.
  Given the result, I can choose to exit.
- With a `true` or a `false` to allow or prevent the default action of the event, i.e
  the form being submitted.

The only way seems to be to call `e.preventDefault` right at the start of the event
and then have to handle the submit in the `onTokenised` handler, but that ignores
all other events from other validation libraries that may also be tryng to handle
aspects of the form.

Is what I want to do even possible? Do I have to rewrite my own version of `sagepay.js`
to handle it in a non-synchronous way? I'm not super-experienced with JavaScript, so
I may just have the concepts of how events work totally wrong.

Comment: An alternative approach may be to tell the Sage Pay gateway script to to synchronous AJAX instead of asynchronous. Then when running my own form, the tokenisation result is available when the tokenisation function returns, and at that point (in the submit event) my code can decide whether to prevent the default submit action or not. The sagepay,js script is pretty opaque to me, but it does seem to have a copy of jQuery embedded in it, and a set of options for AJAX, including `async`, but I have no idea how to set those settings from outside the script, if indeed that's possible.

Comment: Another way of stating what I am trying to do: there are a number of events on the form submit, some of which may be doing AJAX calls. I would like the form to submit once ALL the events have completed (including all their promised callbacks) and none of them have found an error and subsequently issued `preventDefault`, If I have to submit the form in JS (which I would like to avoid), then how can I wait for all the submit events to finish their thing (and presumably flag up any errors they find)?